# How to setup "all traffic" VPN on Linksys WRT54GL (DD-WRT) through Thomson ADSL Router

Tags: vpn, dd-wrt

[Apols if I get terminology wrong...n00b to this!]

I have a (pretty unconfigurable) ISP provided Thomson ADSL router - ISP runs PPPoE.  I added to this a Linksys WRT54GL router which I want to keep entirely for VPN connections back to the UK.

I want to have the Thomson for "standard" traffic - and only able to see other computers on the Thomson, and the same for the Linksys - except route ALL traffic through the VPN client.

Thomson LAN -> Linksys WAN

My Linksys obtains a WAN IP address from the Thomson, and I have its LAN IP set to 192.168.2.1 (Thomson is 192.168.1.1).  Linksys correctly dishes out IP's from its DHCP server and neither network can "see" each other, as far as connected devices go.

However, I'm having issues setting up the VPN client.

If I set the Linksys "Advanced Routing" to Gateway, then I get an internet connection, but no VPN.
If I set the Linksys to "Router" then I don't get an internet connection?

Not entirely sure which settings matter and which don't and can't find a tutorial that is actually useful...they all appear to be concerned with VPN Server or single IP routing...I just want all traffic through the Linksys to be over VPN.

(I live in the Middle East, so I want my XBox, TV and BluRay, along with laptops and iPhone to all think they are still in the UK - BUT I still want to be able to connect without VPN as a lot of sites where I live are restricted INTERNALLY - e.g. government sites, paying utility bills etc.)

Thanks for any assistance, pointers as to what to check etc.